# Python only printing last element of the list

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am a Python newbie using Jupyter Notebook, and I am coming across the following problem:

I create 2 very simple lists and assign them to their own respective variables, which works fine.

My code is below:

```
x = [-2,1,3]
y = [-1,1,2]
```

I then execute other pieces of simple code, which involves using Matplotlib to plot a graph with values from the lists and also multiplying each element in the lists.

However, I noticed when I try to print the original lists after initialising them, I **only get the last element** from the list as an integer, not in list form. I find this strange as I haven't made any changes to the lists.
The issue isn't prominent, because I'm still able to continue to use the lists in their original form e.g. to plot the graph, but I'm wondering why this is happening, hoping to strengthen my Python/programming knowledge...

[image: Screenshot of Jupyter notebook issue]

I've added screenshots to display my issue more clearly, but please ask me to explain anything if I haven't made myself clear.

Thanks in advance everyone!!

Comment: We need [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `88` was evaluated before `93` so `x` has changed from being an `int` to a `list`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually didn't realise the numbers on the left meant the code was executed in that order. As obvious as this may seem to others, as I am a newbie... I think I understand the issue now but where would the output from line 88 have come from in the first place?

Comment: @fashioncoder could've been an `x=3` statement

Comment: If you 'Kernel' -> 'Restart & Run All', then provide us the outputs. Since your In/Out numbering isn't consecutive, it looks like you've assigned 3 to `x`, printed it, the reassigned a list to it.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much guys I didn't realise the issue was with the execution order. Apologies for the naive question!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue in your output of Jupyter, because you pass from the line 93 to 88 and between we don't see the instructions you used.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong , but your problem is that you are giving the same name for both the iterator and the sequence in line 85. instead of doing this:

```
     xy = [x*y for x,y in zip(x,y)]
```

try this:

```
     xy = [i*j for i,j in zip(x,y)]
```